# Corner Radius of both HStack and TextField not updating

Tags: swift, swiftui, contentview

This is the code for my content view. As you can see, I've tried both an HStack to contain the TextField, as well as just the TextField on its own. The corner radius doesn't have any bearing on the grey search rectangle - the edges are still perfectly rectangular.

```
    
    @State var searchText = ""
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            //function that's the content argument to ZStack
            Color((.systemGreen))
            VStack {
                Text("App")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                //HStack {
                TextField("Searchstring", text: $searchText)
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color(.systemGray6))
                    .padding()
                    .cornerRadius(12)
                //}
//                .padding()
//                .background(Color(.systemGray6))
//                .padding(.horizontal)
//                .cornerRadius(12)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is what the preview looks like, in all cases:
[corner radius fails to show in preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmmFm.png)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
.padding() /// 1.
.background(Color(.systemGray6)) /// 2.
.padding() /// 3.
.cornerRadius(12) /// 4.
```

1. Your text field has a `padding`
2. `background` gets applied, after the `padding`
3. You add another `padding`, after the `background`
4. You apply another `cornerRadius` on top of `padding`

As a result, it's the `padding` that gets rounded, not the `background`.

[image: Diagram showing transparent padding rounded]

Instead, you want to apply the `cornerRadius` immediately after the `background`.

[image: Diagram showing background rounded, then padding on outside]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var searchText = ""
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            //function that's the content argument to ZStack
            Color((.systemGreen))
            VStack {
                Text("App")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                
                TextField("Searchstring", text: $searchText)
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color(.systemGray6))
                    .cornerRadius(12) /// corner radius immediately after the background
                    .padding() /// extra padding outside the background
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Background is rounded, then padding applied outside]